# How to add a trendline to my graph in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, graph, trendline, qcustomplot

I want to add a trendline to my graph in Qt.

How to plot a trendline on a line graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to compute a trendline mathematically:

Slope:

[image]

Offset:

[image]

Trendline formula:

[image]

where

```
a is slope
x is the horizontal axis value
b is the Y-intercept
```

Normally you have sccattered data that makes up your graph.
No matter if you use QtWidget or QML you can follow these steps.

- First, find the average of the x values and the average of y values.
- Next, find the distance between each x value and the average of the x values, and the distance between each y value and the average of the y values.
- Then multiplying `(x(i) - X(i)) by (y(i) - Y(i))` , and multiplying `(x(i) - X(i))` by itself.
- Get the sum of first formula (`(x(i) - X(i)) by (y(i) - Y(i))`) and sum of second formula ( `(x(i) - X(i))` )
- Find the slop a by dividing first formula sum by second formula sum.
- Get the average value of x and y and find b value using trendline formula : y = ax + b so b = y - ax

Then you have everything you want to apply your trendline equation

Using your equation, you could now draw your line trend on your QCustomPLot using two point:

```
QCPItemStraightLine *trendLine = new QCPItemStraightLine(customPlot);
trendLine->point1->setCoords(x, y);  // location of point 1 in plot coordinate
trendLine->point2->setCoords(xx, yy);  // location of point 2 in plot coordinate
```